# Variable Interval Timer

Tags: .net, algorithm, timer

I'm writing a custom timer class that'll raise an event with a *variable interval* depending on the timer of day (and possibly day of week) to trigger a refresh of data. As for granularity, I'll probably have different intervals at the hour level.

The best option I've come up with so far is to use a 24 element array. Whenever the timer ticks, you'd take the current hour (24hr) and index into the array to get the new timer interval. I'd probably need some logic to handle situations where going from a long to short interval would cause some expected refreshes to be missed (e.g. if we are going from a long to short interval, truncate at the top of the hour).

I'm looking for an elegant way to do this that is clear to anyone maintaining my code, and easy to work with in code. Are there better algorithms/ways to do this?

**Extra details:**

There is a manual refresh that could be triggered by the user, which would cause the timer to reset. Therefore, the timer isn't going to necessary tick "on-the-hour" or any other regular interval (like `1:15, 1:30, 1:45`). The user may trigger a refresh 2 minutes after we just checked, so if we're checking every 15 minutes, we may end up with something like: `1:15, 1:30, 1:32, 1:47` (user manually refreshed at `1:32`, so we reset the timer and auto-refreshed 15 minutes from that point in time).

Since that interval would be standard across the system I'm developing, I'm okay with hard-coding it. There's no need for it to be a generic interval timer at this point (although solutions that are generic in nature are welcome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you need the following activities to be achieved by the timer subsystem
1. A auto trigger of the system refresh at a predefined interval.
2. A user triggered of the system refresh which can be at any instance.
3. A `ticker` which monitors both the above and triggers the refresh.

I have some pointers below - though may not completely answer all your doubts
1. Above three tasks listed can be identified as part of 3 different threads. Which together will set and unset the event. i.e Task 1, and 2 will set an event and task 3 will unset and event, These events are one and the same shared among threads.
2. Now for the point - 1, i.e pre-defined interval, the solution becomes more simpler. For each interval (i.e suppose you have scheduled refresh for 10min, 13 min etc), from the current time, calculate the next differential time and when it is zero, you can set the event.

Ofcourse, you can improve the abstraction by modelling `interval`,`Event(s)` etc. But from my experience, for low-level precision based requirement such as timer, scheduling etc, I feel a more **`C`** kind of approach is far more suitable.
HTH!